# Which calculation is correct/used in which case for adjusted Skewness?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, stata, skewness

I was looking at the wikipedia page for skewness here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness and under the section on sample skewness the following modification is shown for sample skewness:

[image]

However, the coefficients shown on the first line and second line are not mathematically the same despite this working claiming them to be. I have seen both referenced as being used by computer programms when calculating sample skeweness but I also looked up the SPSS manual which says they use this as the modifying coefficient:

[image]

Which unlike the other two does not approach 1 as x approaches infinity.

My questions are:

1) Am I correct in saying this is an error on wikipedia?

2) Why would STATA use a coefficient that increases beyond 1, or is this a mistake and they use something else?

3) Does anyone have any resources listing the different methods of other programs?

Thanks

Comment: can you share the link for the stata manual?

Comment: @gunes https://www.stata.com/manuals13/rsktest.pdf